# Python function declare a dynamic global variable

Tags: python, global, sympy

I saw the code below and I'm speechless. Here it is:

```
>>> import sympy
>>> sympy.var('x')
x
>>> x
x
>>> type(x)
<class 'sympy.core.symbol.Symbol'>
>>>
```

Notice that that the variable `x` has never been assigned. What's going on?

In my opinion the function `sympy.var` accepts a string as an input parameter and declares a global variable of type `sympy.core.symbol.Symbol` whose name is equivalent to the parameter. So every time the function is called, a new variable will be available whose name is the last parameter passed to the function.

Comment: Without looking at the sympy code, my guess would be it is updating the `globals()`

Comment: Note that `var` is intended only for interactive usage. If you are writing a script, you should assign variables the normal way, using `symbols`.

Answer (score 3):

To add some details to @Stephen Rauch's answer, have a look at core source code:

```
from inspect import currentframe
frame = currentframe().f_back

try:
    syms = symbols(names, **args)

    if syms is not None:
        if isinstance(syms, Basic):
            frame.f_globals[syms.name] = syms
        elif isinstance(syms, FunctionClass):
            frame.f_globals[syms.__name__] = syms
        else:
            traverse(syms, frame)
finally:
    del frame  # break cyclic dependencies as stated in inspect docs
```

As you can see, using `inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_globals`, you can get current `globals`.

Answer (score 1):

From the ([DOCS](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.2/modules/core.html#sympy.core.symbol.var))

```
sympy.core.symbol.var(names, **args)
```

> Create symbols and inject them into the global namespace.

Comment: If you add a small example I am confident that it will totally solve what I am asking for.

Comment: What?  This 100% explains your question.  IE by design